# Does the minimum singular value of a matrix smaller than that of its restricted one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, singular-values

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Let $\sigma_{min}(A)$ be the minimum singular value of matrix $A$. Let $A_r$ be a restriction of matrix $A$ to some rows.
Is $\sigma_{min}(A) \leq \sigma_{min}(A_r)$?

Comment: @user1551: Can you please elaborate on that or provide me with a proof?

Comment: @Sepide In other words, $\sigma_\min(A) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$

Comment: @Ben Grossmann: but how does that show the minimum singular value of the bigger matrix is smaller than the minimum singular value of smaller matrix?

Comment: @Sepide That's where we hoped you would fill in the blanks. To be a bit more explicit: show that for every $x$, $\|Ax\| \geq \|A_r x\|$

Comment: @Ben Grossmann: I am not sure how to show it, if know where to start, I may do it. Actually, I am confused about $\sigma_{min}(A)=\min{||x||=1}||Ax||$ because I always seen this as a formula for minimum eigenvalue. I this case $A$ is a not a square matrix.

Comment: Try it for an example. Write out $\|Ax\|^2$ and $\|A_r x\|^2$ for $m=3,n=2$ in terms of the entries of $A$ and $x$. Take $A_r$ to be the restriction to the first two rows

Comment: @Ben Grossmann: I got what you meant $\|Ax\|^2=\|A_rx\|^2+\|A_{r^c}x\|^2$ for all $x$ where $r^c$ is the set of rows that are not restricted. Hence, $\|Ax\|^2 \geq \|A_rx\|^2$ for all $x$. Now out of this how do show the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true if $A$ is a square or “fat” matrix, and false otherwise.

A counterexample first: let $A=\pmatrix{0\\ 1}$ and $A_r$ be the first row of $A$. Then $\sigma_\min(A_r)=0<1=\sigma_\min(A)$. Note that $A$ is “tall” in this counterexample.

Now suppose $A$ is square or fat. Without loss of generality we may assume that $A_r$ consists of the first $k$ rows of $A$. Then $A^T$ and $A_r^T$ are tall matrices and the latter is composed of the first $r$ columns of the former. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma_\min(A)
=\sigma_\min(A^T)
&=\min_{\substack{u\in\mathbb R^m\\ \|u\|=1}}\|A^Tu\|_2\\
&\le\min_{\substack{v\in\mathbb R^k\\ \|v\|=1}}\left\|A^T\pmatrix{v\\ 0}\right\|_2\\
&=\min_{\substack{v\in\mathbb R^k\\ \|v\|=1}}\|A_r^Tv\|_2\\
&=\sigma_\min(A_r^T)=\sigma_\min(A_r).
\end{aligned}
$$